# Are there any ways to get dependency graph for project?

Tags: typescript

Actually I'm looking for something like `-M` key in `gcc` but for `tsc`

Comment: I see NPM module typescript-dependency-util but it is out of date, last update 3/4/15, fails to work on current TS. It could probably serve as an example of how to make a dependency graph generator.

Answer (score 32):

[Dependency cruiser](https://github.com/sverweij/dependency-cruiser) can generate dependencies graphs:

You may install it via `npm` (it will work with npx regardless):

```
$ npm install --save-dev dependency-cruiser
```

To make sure TypeScript support works you should first run:

```
$ npx depcruise --info
```

You can create a JSON file containing the dependencies between your TypeScript files:

```
$ npx depcruise --no-config \
--exclude "^node_modules" \
--output-type json \
[your_entry_point.ts] > dependencies.json
```

If you have installed the `dot` utility included in `graphviz` you can generate an SVG

```
$ npx depcruise --no-config \
--exclude "^node_modules" \
--output-type dot \
[your_entry_point.ts] > dependencies.dot
$ dot dependencies.dot -T svg -o dependencies.svg
```

Dot support many other [output formats](https://graphviz.org/doc/info/output.html) and `graphviz` is available as a package of most Linux distributions and [other operational systems as well](https://graphviz.org/download/)

Comment: @cdalxndr dependency-cruiser has had triple slash dependency support since the beginning of 2018 ([v2.12.0](https://github.com/sverweij/dependency-cruiser/releases/tag/v2.12.0)) - also see the [answer](https://github.com/sverweij/dependency-cruiser/issues/160)  to the issue you raised in the dependency-cruiser repo on this topic.

Comment: @Sander Yes, I got a response with a working command for tripple slash dependencies. Was going to remove previous comment.

Comment: Is there a way to create a graph visualization (SVG, PNG, JPG, BMP, whatever) on a windows machine?

Comment: With graphviz installed `run dot -Tpng filename.dot -o outfile.png` for more details on output parameters/formats - graphviz.org/doc/info/output.html

Comment: As mentioned in the [docs](https://github.com/sverweij/dependency-cruiser/blob/develop/doc/cli.md) I had to specify the source directory, not the entry point. Specifying the entrypoint led to a graph limited to that one file.

Comment: Default command didn't work for me. Alternative `npx depcruise src --no-config --include-only "^src" --output-type dot | dot -T svg > dependency-graph.svg`

Answer (score 22):

I created [ts-dependency-graph](https://github.com/PSeitz/ts-dependency-graph), since dependency cruiser did never finish for my rather large project. It contains some options to handle large dependency graphs.

```
npm i ts_dependency_graph -g

ts_dependency_graph --start src/index.ts
```

Copy output e.g. to https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/

```
 ts_dependency_graph --help
Options:
  --help                        Show help                              [boolean]
  --version                     Show version number                    [boolean]
  --start                       the starting file, for the analysis     [string]
  --aggregate_by_folder, --agg  create graph on folder level
                                                      [boolean] [default: false]
  --max_depth                                           [number] [default: 1000]
  --filter                      filters files containing the provided strings
                                                           [array] [default: []]
  --verbose, -v                 prints information about ignored files
                                                      [boolean] [default: false]
  --hotspots, -h                identify hotspots, by analyzing number of
                                incoming and outgoing edges
                                                      [boolean] [default: false]
  --base_path                   calculates path relatives to the base path
   [string] [default: "/currentpath"]
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks! You helped me debug an annoying dependency that would have taken a long time otherwise

Comment: @Pieter If it was circular dependencies that were causing you issues then you can also use Madge, which you can also easily make part of your build pipeline. https://www.npmjs.com/package/madge