# How can I get the import graph of ES6 and TypeScript code?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to get the import graph of a given ES6 or TypeScript file. I would like the output in a machine readable format, such as DOT or JSON. If TypeScript and ES6 require different tools then I would like both solutions.

Imports are like this:

```js
import foo from 'foo';
import { bar } from 'bar';
```

What can I use to achieve this?

Comment: A quick google search lead me to [node-dependency-tree](https://github.com/dependents/node-dependency-tree). Did you already take a look at this? If yes, why does it not work for your case?

Comment: Also this question is worth a look if it is similar (I'm not sure if it's about node dependencies or imports): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40852578/are-there-any-ways-to-get-dependency-graph-for-project

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there any ways to get dependency graph for project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40852578/are-there-any-ways-to-get-dependency-graph-for-project)